# Fetch List of Custom Objects present on another Org

Tags: apex, soap-api, metadata-api, partner-wsdl

I have a requirement where I need to fetch list of objects present on another Org. I tried it using metadata service but could not fetch.Any Idea how this can be done using Partner WSDL or ToolsLink API. I am pasting my sample code using metadta service.

```
public void fetchMetadata()
    {
        a = TestMetadata.createService();
        a.describeMetadata(29);
        MetadataService.DescribeMetadataResult describeRes = new MetadataService.DescribeMetadataResult();
        describeRes = a.describeMetadata(29);
        List<MetadataService.DescribeMetadataObject> objectList = describeRes.MetadataObjects;
         if (objectList.size() > 0) {
            for (MetadataService.DescribeMetadataObject obj : objectList) {
                system.debug('****'+obj.XmlName);

            }
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The metadata API isn't for retrieving records, it is for retrieving information about the structure of those records. E.g. what fields are on a custom object and what data type each field is.

The partner API isn't really intended for consumption from Apex. It includes a number of schema features that aren't supported by Wsdl2Apex.

One of these is the `any` element on the complexType sObject. This is important, as it is this element that would contain the sObject fields (beyond the Id) when retrieved via a SOQL query.

E.g.

This will work if you have at least one Account in the target org and have the remote site settings setup to include https://login.salesforce.com and https://*targetOrgPod*.salesforce.com

```
partnerSoapSforceCom.Soap partner = new partnerSoapSforceCom.Soap();
partnerSoapSforceCom.LoginResult lr=partner.login('test@example.com', 'myPasswordInPlainText!PlusTheSecurityToken');
partnerSoapSforceCom.SessionHeader_element header=new partnerSoapSforceCom.SessionHeader_element();
header.sessionId=lr.sessionId;
partner.SessionHeader=header;
partner.endpoint_x = lr.serverUrl;
partnerSoapSforceCom.QueryResult qr = partner.Query('Select Id from Account limit 1');
System.debug('Number of Query results:' + qr);
sobjectPartnerSoapSforceCom.sObject_x result1 = qr.records[0];
System.debug(result1);
```

However, if you add anything to the returned field set beyond Id you will get an error due to the missing any element. Here is what happens when I try the SOQL `Select Id, Name from Account limit 1`.

> System.CalloutException: Web service callout failed: Unable to parse callout response. Apex type not found for element Name: Class.DFB.partnerSoapSforceCom.Soap.query: line 2048, column 1 AnonymousBlock: line 7, column 1 AnonymousBlock: line 7, column 1

You could potentially use the Enterprise WSDL, which will include explicit elements for each field. It won't be able to dynamically handle changes in schema though.

---

You might be better served by an alternative method of retrieving the data, such as:

- [Salesforce to Salesforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salesforce2salesforce)
- The [REST API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/) to retrieve the required records
- Creating a [WebService method](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_web_services.htm) in Apex from the source org that returns the required data.

Comment: @Sonal. I'm glad it worked. Which solution did you go with?
Also, there is a green tick towards the top of the answer that can be used to indicate it as such. This makes the answer clearer to future users.